# jQuery Mobile Transitions processing twice

Tags: jquery-mobile

My transitions are jerky and some time seem to process twice. So its not a smooth fluid transition from page to page. Am I doing something wrong within the coding? This was tested on an iPhone 4S with the latest update.

```
<div data-role="page" id="track_dash">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h3><!-- ex: Phase 1, Day 1 --> Phase #, Day # </h3>
        <a data-role="button" data-transition="flip" data-theme="b" class="ui-btn-right" href="#page2"> Info </a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="360">
            <img src="simgs/360_logo.png" /><!-- style="width: 170px; height: 91px" -->
        </div>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
            <li data-theme="c">
                <a href="#page4" data-transition="slide"> Track Meals </a>
            </li>
            <li data-theme="c">
                <a href="#page20" data-transition="slide"> Track Workouts </a>
            </li>
            <li data-theme="c">
                <a href="#page8" data-transition="slide"> Track Progress </a>
            </li>
            <li data-theme="c">
                <a href="#page17" data-transition="slide"> Journal </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="d" data-inset="true">
            <li data-theme="d">
                <a href="#page52" data-transition="slide"> <img src="simgs/alert_bubble.png" alt="Alerts" class="ui-li-icon" /> Alerts <span class="ui-li-count">2</span> </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div data-theme="e" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#page1" id="track" data-theme="e" data-icon="custom" data-corners="false" data-iconshow="true" data-wrapperels="span" class="ui-btn-active"> <span class="foot_font">Track</span> </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#page40" id="cal" data-theme="e" data-icon="custom" data-corners="false" data-iconshow="true" data-wrapperels="span"> <span class="foot_font">Calendar</span> </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#page44" id="shop" data-theme="e" data-icon="custom" data-corners="false" data-iconshow="true" data-wrapperels="span"> <span class="foot_font">Shopping</span> </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#page22" id="profile" data-theme="e" data-icon="custom" data-corners="false" data-iconshow="true" data-wrapperels="span"> <span class="foot_font">Profile</span> </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#page47" id="more" data-theme="e" data-icon="custom" data-corners="false" data-iconshow="true" data-wrapperels="span"> <span class="foot_font">More</span> </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I only see the one page, no JS, could you add a little more? demo link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be caused by [this issue](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4024) - jquery mobile 1.1. It is especially visible as you have set data-position="fixed" in your header.
There are some answers in that issue, read it until the end.

Otherwise to be more specific you would need to describe what browser you use or mobile OS if you don't know, and the version of jqm you're using.

Comment: data-position fixed is causing the problem. I'm looking for a work around right now because I'd like to keep the fixed headers. Fixed headers was the main reason for update jQuery Mobile versions

Comment: I had to disable the fixed headers because of that flickering effect. I think the jqm team is aware of this problem and they're trying to fix it for 1.1.1, but [it doesn't look like it's gonna be out too soon](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/milestones) unfortunately..